# Python constructor weirdness

Tags: python, class, oop

I have this simple code:

```
class bfs:
    vis=[]
    bags=[]
    def __init__ (self,x): 
        for i in p:    #initializes vis with len(p) zeroes 
            self.vis.append(0)
            print self.vis
        self.vis[x]=1   #marks index x as visited
        print self.vis

p=raw_input("Input values: ").split()
for i in range(0,len(p)):
    p[i]=int(p[i])

q=[]
for i in range(0,len(p)):
    q.append(bfs(i))

print
for i in q:
    print i.vis
```

If i input, say, any 3 numbers, why do I get this output:

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Instead of something like this?

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]

[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
```

The program seems to just keep on working with one array in all created objs. Why is this the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Related: [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining defining `vis` and `bags` as part of the class (as "attribute references"), instead of in the constructor. Try this instead:

```
class bfs:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.vis = []
        self.bags = []
        # etc.
```

The [documentation for class objects](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) may help:

> Attribute references use the standard syntax used for all attribute references in Python: obj.name. Valid attribute names are all the names that were in the class’s namespace when the class object was created. So, if the class definition looked like this:
>
> ```
> class MyClass:
>     """A simple example class"""
>     i = 12345
>     def f(self):
>         return 'hello world'
> ```
>
> then MyClass.i and MyClass.f are valid attribute references, returning an integer and a function object, respectively. Class attributes can also be assigned to, so you can change the value of MyClass.i by assignment.

There's also a [Dive Into Python page](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/class_attributes.html) about this:

> Class attributes are available both through direct reference to the class and through any instance of the class.
>
> Note: In Java, both static variables (called class attributes in Python) and instance variables (called data attributes in Python) are defined immediately after the class definition (one with the static keyword, one without). **In Python, only class attributes can be defined here; data attributes are defined in the `__init__` method.**

Comment: That did indeed do the trick. I had no idea you had to do things this way in Python. Thanks